# For loop of HTTP requests not working (Node.js, S3, javascript)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, amazon-s3

I'm pretty new to this. Any help would really help!!!!!!

Basically it's a system where Angular runs through an array of files and then makes upload requests to the server. The first step that the server takes is to add the file to the database, and then to upload the file.

Angular is sending the files correctly [1,2,3,4] but when the SERVER goes to post the data to the database, I'm finding that it repeats random objects and skips other ones.

This is really confusing me.

Here is my code:

Angular:

```
       for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            console.log('angular uploading file!')
            console.log(files[i].trackNumber)
          Upload.upload({
            url: '/../api/createTrack', 
            data: {file: files[i].trackFile, trackUserName: scope.username, trackNumber: files[i].trackNumber, trackName: files[i].trackName, trackAlbum: scope.albumName, trackArtist: scope.artistEditName, trackArtistImage: scope.currentArtistData.artistImage, trackAlbumTrackLength: scope.tracks.length},
                file: files[i].trackFile
            })
        }.then(function (res) {
        console.log('Success ' + res.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + res.data)
            }, function (res) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + res.status)
            }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total)
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name)
            })
```

Node.js:

```
createTrack.prototype.uploadFile = function(req, res) {

    var file = req.files.file;

    addWavFile = function(trackWavSource){
        read_file = fs.readFileSync(file.path)
        var params = {Bucket: 'dogatracks', Key: trackWavSource, Body: read_file, ACL:"public-read"}
        s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error uploading data: ", err)
            } else {
            etc

    addTrackToDatabase = function(artistId, albumId, trackAlbumArt, trackWavSource){
        const dateAdded = new Date()
        Track
        .create({
            trackName:req.body.trackName,
            trackNumber: req.body.trackNumber,
            trackAlbum: req.body.trackAlbum,
            ETC
```

Now, it works, the files are sometimes uploaded pretty well, however sometimes for some reason the files duplicate in the database... here is what the logs output for instance:

```
addtodatabase:
1
add File:
1
addtodatabase:
1
add File:
1
addtodatabase:
3
add File:
3
addtodatabase:
4
add File:
4
```

As you can see, the system generally works, but for some reason the file randomly will repeat itself! The first track was uploaded twice, and added to the database twice. This doesn't just happen to the first track. Also, sometimes all the tracks upload fine. In the Angular log, the files are always sent as 1,2,3,4 in correct order. I feel like I'm missing something about how the server/HTTP actually works.

Does this have something to do with timing? I don't get how it is that the server would miss requests or repeat a request, because Angular is clearly sending the correct information inside of the loop each time.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

New clues:

Each time the server side code is requested, the code makes a unique ID for the request:
1a6e4ef9-48bf-4612-8562-8b38ab1b6725
Inside the database, each of the 444 track objects has the same ID! So clearly the server isn't really "firing" the function again for that track object. Within the function, for whatever reason, the server is outputting the object over and over again. Like when the function gets a new request, instead of operating on the new info (or something) it fires the current info to Mongoose again? I might have to just re-write the entire system though it would be preferable to make this work - though I can see there might be better approaches.

Comment: you aren't confirming the upload success (or error) in the angular code.

Comment: I added that just now and I'm still getting same problem, for instance:

Comment: I uploaded tracks 1,2,3,4,5 and this is what ended up going through:  1, 4, 4, 4, 5

Comment: Did get this in the console in Chrome:

Comment: Success 1.wavuploaded. Response:... Success 4.wavuploaded. ...Success 5.wavuploaded. Response: ... (2 and 3 didn't post but 4 was added 3 times to the database)

Answer (score 0):

```
scope.uploadTracks = function (files) {
        console.log('angular track upload:')
        console.log(files)
      if (files && files.length) {
        var i = -1
            if (i < files.length){
                $timeout(function(){i+=1}, 100)
                scope.$watch(function(){return i},
                        function(){
                        console.log('angular uploading file!')
                        console.log(files[i].trackNumber)
                      Upload.upload({
                        url: '/../api/createTrack', 
                        data: {file: files[i].trackFile, trackUserName: scope.username, trackNumber: files[i].trackNumber, trackName: files[i].trackName, trackAlbum: scope.albumName, trackArtist: scope.artistEditName, trackArtistImage: scope.currentArtistData.artistImage, trackAlbumTrackLength: scope.tracks.length},
                            file: files[i].trackFile
                        }).then(function (res) {
                    console.log('Success ' + res.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + res.data)
                    i+=1
                    //when this is successful, it should upload the next file.
                        }, function (res) {
                    console.log('Error status: ' + res.status)
                        }, function (evt) {
                    scope.uploadProgress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total)
                    console.log('progress: ' + scope.uploadProgress + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name)
                        })
                        }
                    )
          }
        }
    }
```

I rewrote the function. It is now, for the time being, working. The function makes use of a watcher in Angular to wait until the track is uploaded to send the next one. This works. Can't say that I know intellectually that it will work forever, but as of right now it is functioning properly each time I run it.